# How to pass date arguments for requests.get command for API data?

Tags: python-2.7, api, curl, subprocess, python-requests

I'm trying to get past weather data from API source. However I'm running into issues on how to pass the date arguments and specify dates I'm trying to get data for. I have been successful in using curl GET command, but not been successful in translating that over to requests.get command.

Here's what works:

```
curl -X GET -G "http://url.com/lat/long" -d start="2018-04-01" -d end="2018-04-04" --user abcd:1234
```

Using subprocess command I have gotten that code to work.Here's the code below:

```
cmd = 'curl -X GET -G "http://url.com/lat/long" -d start="2018-04-01"  -d end="2018-04-04" --user abcd:1234'

p = sp.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT).stdout.read()

p.split('\n')[3]
```

Here's the code I have for requests.get:

```
r=requests.get("https://url.com/lat/long",auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','password'))
```

However, cannot pass the date arguments through to limit my data pull to my specified date ranges.

Here's a couple of method's I have tried.

```
r=requests.get("https://url.com/lat/long",start=start,end=end,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','password'))
```

Also tried:

```
data = [
  ('startDate', '2018-04-01'),
  ('endDate', '2018-04-08'),
]

r=requests.get("https://url.com/lat/long",data=data,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','password'))
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction? I really want to stick with the request library command, but only thing thats working right now is running the curl command through the subprocess method, and I don't fully understand that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `G` parameter in your `curl` command:

```
-G, --get           Put the post data in the URL and use GET
```

This means that your data will not be submitted in the body of the request, but in the url as a query string. With `requests` you can use the [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) argument to achieve that.

So your `curl` command is equivalent to:

```
import requests

url = 'https://url.com/lat/long'
data = {'start': '2018-04-01', 'end': '2018-04-08'}
creds = ('user','password')
r = requests.get(url, params=data, auth=creds)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue. Just needed to properly call the params. Appreciate it, the requests.get method is going to save me sooo much time.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
data = {
  'start': '2018-04-01',
  'end': '2018-04-08'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gave that a try, but it doesn't really change the start and end dates when i hit the api. The api is still showing me todays date, not the dates i specified. It's completely ignoring the data=data argument in the requests.get code

Comment: @pewpewpew does the auth ok? if you will do the request without the auth, do will get the same response? basic-auth means adding specific header to the request and not `--user ...`